# How to run yWorks UML Doclet from within Eclipse

Tags: java, uml, javadoc

I'm trying to follow the instructions to set up yWorks through the eclipse wizard.

The instruction are as follows:
  1.        Select Export from the File menu.
  2.        Choose Javadoc from Select an export destination.Go to the next tab.
  3.        Select Use Custom Doclet then specify Doclet name and Doclet class path.Name has to be ydoc.doclets.YStandard and path has to be /lib/ydoc.jar.
 denotes the absolute path to the yDoc directory.
Go to the next tab.(*I can't go to the next tab*)Add in Extra Javadoc options -docletpath /resources

But in the javadoc generation wizard it says "Specify the Javadoc command". It won't let me proceed witout it. What command should I specify?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand it now, eclipse was looking for the path to the javadoc.exe as a command.